# Drag&Drop using Winapi for Third-Party Control

Tags: delphi, winapi, drag-and-drop, activex

I need to integrate drag&drop of our existing application with a new component.

Our application uses Winapi.ActiveX do implement this. The new component comes with its own drag&drop events which aren't Winapi-compatible, though.

The main problem for now is dragging things into the new control. Dragging out of it should be achievable, if all else fails by caching the object under the cursor on mouse down.

As I understand it you can't override drag&drop registration, that is if I call RegisterDragDrop on the component before they do it somewhere in their code, I'll be the one holding the registration.

The observed behavior, however, is that calling RegisterDragDrop reports success, but dragging something over the control doesn't lead to a DragEnter event on the IDropTarget. Their drag&drop event fires just fine, even after RegisterDragDrop, but as I said, the returned data object only holds valid data for a select few types of draggable objects.

I also tried registering the panel that contains this component for drag&drop, but that didn't work either.

What would you suggest?

Update:

I realized, I was trying to register the wrong handle. When I try to register the right handle, I actually get a drag&drop already registered error.

I guess I didn't formulate it too clearly, but the question is, how do you implement drag&drop for a closed-source component that already has it's own implementation, which doesn't provide enough flexibility for your taste?

What I can think of:

1. Bug the developer of the component until they change the component.
2. Do some API hooking to go in between the component's implementation and the OS.
3. Hopefully something else that is simple.

Update:

Thanks so far, now I can drag things into the control the way I want it.
The next step is dragging things out. Here the problem is that other drop targets in the application don't understand the control's IDataObject. For a different control we already have code that uses IDataObject::SetData to append data in a format that all the application's drop targets can understand.

The difference with the new control, however is that when it initiates a drag&drop operation, it doesn't use a IDataObject that has IDataObject::SetData implemented (returns E_NOTIMPL); Is there a way to replace the IDataObject with a different one, while the d&d operation is ongoing?

Comment: Try `RevokeDragDrop` and then register it again with your own `IDropTarget` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset already registered IDropTarget of your ActiveX control after control creation with the following code:

```
const
  sOleDropTargetInterface = 'OleDropTargetInterface';

procedure ResetDropTarget(AWnd: HWND);
var
  Unknown: IUnknown;
begin
  Unknown := IUnknown(GetProp(AWnd, PChar(GlobalFindAtom(sOleDropTargetInterface))));
  if Assigned(Unknown) then
    try
      if not SetProp(AWnd, PChar(GlobalFindAtom(sOleDropTargetInterface)), 0) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      Unknown._Release;
    finally
      Unknown := nil;
    end;
end;
```

Update

kobik points the right solution: using of RevokeDragDrop function.

Comment: That's an awesome idea. Now I'm using GetProp to get the control's internal 
IDropTarget, which I can then use to call the controls internal drag&drop 
handling whenever I want. This helps me find out, if the d&d operation 
originated from within the control.